# Adding a CAShapeLayer around a button

Tags: ios, swift

I created a CAShapeLayer in the shape of a circle, and I want to add it around I button i have in the view. I am doing this instead of a border, due to animation purposes. I don't want a border around the button, I'd rather have a shape. This is how I am adding it, but for some reason, it is not adding the shape directly around the button.

This is my code to add the layer

```
recordLine = CAShapeLayer()
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: recordButton.center, radius: recordButton.frame.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
recordLine.path = circularPath.cgPath
recordLine.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
recordLine.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
recordLine.lineWidth = 5
view.layer.addSublayer(recordLine)
```

This is how it is adding the line for some reason.[image: Actual position of the layer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are adding Shape layer before rendering the autolayout Constrain properly.

Please add a single line before adding shape layer : self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

```
 @IBOutlet weak var roundButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        roundButton.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        roundButton.clipsToBounds = true
        roundButton.alpha = 0.5
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let recordLine = CAShapeLayer()
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: roundButton.center, radius: roundButton.frame.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: false)
        recordLine.path = circularPath.cgPath
        recordLine.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        recordLine.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        recordLine.lineWidth = 10
        view.layer.addSublayer(recordLine)

    }
```

Please check the reference image [image]
This is working for me.

Comment: Now it is adding it below the button, still not working

Comment: i have modified the answer please check. Please take a class property assign it to nil and write it in override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() method with the check of nil so that memory will be allocated once and add it.

Comment: yes im calling view.layoutIfNeeded() all it did was move it below the button rather than on the top. It is not showing it around the button

Comment: Do you have your code on any repository if it is i can help in that.

Comment: Hmm i called it in the override viewdidlayoutsubviews method, and now it is adding two layers. One around the button as I wish, and then another around the same exact button

Comment: you can make class variable for that shape and add a if check so that it will not allocate the memory twice and it will not add any extra circle.

Comment: Please add the member variable for shape layer and also add check for nil so that it will bot be added twice. If this will work for you mark it up so that it will help other also.

Comment: adding the **CAShapeLayer** to **viewDidLayoutSubview** is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My button is programmatic. I had to add the the `cashapelayer` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
lazy var cameraButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return button
}()

var wasCAShapeLayerAddedToCameraButton = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    if !wasCAShapeLayerAddedToCameraButton {
        wasCAShapeLayerAddedToCameraButton = true
        
        cameraButton.layer.cornerRadius = cameraButton.frame.width / 2
        
        addCAShapeLayerToCameraButton()
    }
}

func addCAShapeLayerToCameraButton() {
    
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: cameraButton.center,
                                    radius: (cameraButton.frame.width / 2),
                                    startAngle: 0,
                                    endAngle: 2 * .pi,
                                    clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

// try like this i hope it will work for you. 
Note: Color and other properties change as your requirement

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.name = "Star"
    let path: CGPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: recordButton.center, radius: recordButton.frame.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayer.path = path
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Comment: thats not what im looking for